# Where does Piccolo's new transformation fit in the power scale?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

So many months ago before the release of *Dragon Ball Super: Super Her*o, we've been teased about Piccolo having a new transformation. Now that the new movie has been released in Japan, and summaries are appearing everywhere, where does Piccolo's new transformation fit in the power scale?